# Seleção multi-linha no VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Existe alguma forma de fazer seleção multi-linha no VS Code, da forma como se faz no Sublime e em outras IDE's?

Eu tentei o <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + seta que funciona no Visual Studio, mas ao invés de selecionar multi-linha o VS Code ou seleciona a linha (seta pra direita) ou copia a linha (seta para baixo).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037808/multiline-editing-in-vscode seria isso? Ctrl+alt + seta

Comment: @GabrielHeguedusch ctrl + alt + seta no Windows gira a tela.

Comment: ai é configuração... estou com o w7 e por acaso a minha tela não gira, e o comando funciona de maneira certa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito usando a combinação <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Botão principal do mouse.

Isso vai criando um cursor por linha clicada, segurando o botão do mouse e arrastando para selecionar, permite selecionar várias linhas.

Ou então, é possível usar a combinação 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>↑</kbd> ou <kbd>→</kbd> ou <kbd>↓</kbd> ou <kbd>←</kbd>).

Onde, as setas pra cima e pra baixo são usadas para subir/descer linhas e as setas pra esquerda e pra direita para selecionar parte do texto pro respectivo lado.

[image: Seleção multilinhas no VS Code]

Comment: +1, mas tem como fazer sem mouse?

Comment: @Renan Tava procurando por isso, acabei de editar.

Comment: Funciona até melhor do que no Visual Studio, valeu!

Answer (score 8):

No **VS Code** selecione a *tag* e use as teclas <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Que ele vai selecionando as *tags* abaixo a cada toque em <kbd>D</kbd>.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ctrl+D seleciona apena a pro cima ocorrência da mesma palavra, isso não eh seleção Multi Linha como solicitado na pergunta, isso não responde a pergunta

Answer (score 7):

Vou contribuir com essas 4 formas de selecionar linhas de forma independente usando cliques de mouse e alguns atalhos de teclado.

**Opção 1**

A primeira é segurando <kbd>Alt</kbd> e <kbd>clicando 3x</kbd> em algum caractere da linha (o primeiro clique marca o cursor, o segundo clique seleciona a palavra e o terceiro clique seleciona a frase)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 2**

Nessa opção pressionando <kbd>Alt</kbd> vc clica nas linhas que quer marcar, depois aperta <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> e vai selecionar a linha inteira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Atalho  <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 3**

Nessa opção pressionando <kbd>Alt</kbd> vc clica no início de cada linha que quer selecionar e depois aperta <kbd>Shift + End</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 4**

Pressionando e arrastando o `Wheel Button` do mouse (é só pressionar e arrastar a rodinha de scroll do mouse)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu acredito que o que você esteja procurando é transformar uma seleção em bloco em uma seleção multi linhas, certo?

O que da pra fazer é:

## Windows:

---

#### 1. Selecionar o texto que você deseja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 2. Pressionar as teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Neste momento, você já terá a sua seleção de bloco, transformada em seleção multi linhas.

#### Para selecionar todas as linhas do início ao fim, é só você apertar a tecla <kbd>Home</kbd> e depois apertar as teclas <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

Neste momento, você terá a seleção completa das linhas, individualmente, como na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## MacOS:

---

#### 1. Selecionar o texto que você deseja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 2. Pressionar as teclas <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option/alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Neste momento, você já terá a sua seleção de bloco, transformada em seleção multi linhas.

#### Para selecionar todas as linhas do início ao fim, é só você apertar a tecla <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> e depois apertar as teclas <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Neste momento, você terá a seleção completa das linhas, individualmente, como na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score -1):

CTRL + D =seleciona trechos iguais

CTRL + SHIFT + L = Selecionar todas correspondencias

ALT + Clique do mouse =seleciona pontos com base em cliques

Arrastar Scroll clicado =seleciona com base no arrasto do scroll do mouse

CTRL + F depois ALT + ENTER =pesquisa ocorrencia e depois seleciona todas as ocorrencias

CTRL + F depois ALT + W = perquisar coincidindo palavra inteira

CTRL + F depois ALT + C = pesquisar diferenciando maiuscula de minuscula

CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + Page Down = cursor em varias linhas de forma rapida e facil

depois de qualquer um destes so usar CTRL + L para selecionar as linhas

CTLR + K + S = Atalhos teclado // para caso queira pesquisar comandos